# Indentation of Lisp code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have written some Lisp code, and it works, but I am not sure how to indent it properly.

Basically I have a global variable and three functions:

```
(setf my-hand '((3 hearts)
                (5 clubs)
                (2 diamonds)
                (4 diamonds)
                (ace spades)))

(defun rank (card)
  (car card))

(defun suit (card)
  (cadr card))

(defun count-suit (suit hand)
  (length (remove-if-not #'(lambda (card) (equal suit (suit card))) hand)))
```

I'm fine with the global variable and the functions `rank` and `suit`, but what about `count-suit`? How should I wrap its body and indent it? I can think of several ways, but can't decide on what seems right.

Any hints?

Is there a canonical way of how to do this?

Comment: **setf** doesn't declare global variables.  In fact, the behavior of **setf** on undeclared variables is undefined behavior.  Declare global variables with **defvar** or **defparameter**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I will watch out for this :-)

Comment: Yes, it's a common pitfall, and lots of tutorials, etc., get it wrong.  There are some other things you can do to simplify your code, too, that I've discussed in an [additional answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29638261/1281433).  (Chris's is most directly about the indentation, though. Mine is just about avoiding the need for so much code.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that there is a slight difference between *indenting* and *formatting*.

**Indenting** usually means to move contents of a line horizontally. Usually we know already what is on the line and the line before. If you ask a typical editor to *indent*, it will do nothing more than adjusting the horizontal position of the line content. It will not distribute expressions over lines.

**Formatting** means to layout out code over one or more lines. Lisp provides a pretty printer for automatic layout. But in the editor full layout is not that well supported, especially since the rules can be complicated and it is kind of difficult to deal with comments and other non-s-expression code contents. Layout of macros is based on simple principles. Automatic layout for more complex macros like LOOP would be really difficult.

Your question is actually about *formatting*.

```
(length (remove-if-not #'(lambda (card) (equal suit (suit card))) hand))
```

Can I identify function calls? What are the arguments? What is syntax? What about line-length? Indentation depth?

Let's look at the function calls: place them more prominently:

```
(length
 (remove-if-not
  #'(lambda (card)
      (equal
       suit
       (suit card)))
  hand))
```

Above doesn't look so bad.

Maybe we want to concentrate on the arguments and make sure that two or more arguments are on separate lines:

```
(length (remove-if-not #'(lambda (card)
                           (equal suit
                                  (suit card)))
                       hand))
```

Typically we want short arglists to be on one line, if the line is not too long:

```
(length (remove-if-not #'(lambda (card)
                           (equal suit (suit card)))
                       hand))
```

Above is what I would write in this case. Code structure is clear enough and it does not waste too much space.

Formatting code means applying a lot of local and global constraints/rules.

If we look at the expression, we also would want to write it differently, because it triggers a lot of things one typically does not like:

- it counts, but it does not use a counting function
- it does unnecessary work
- it creates a lambda expression for extracting a value and testing it against an item: extract and test

So:

```
(count suit hand :key #'suit :test #'eql)
```

or just (`eql` is the default):

```
(count suit hand :key #'suit)
```

Back to formatting. We can make a few experiments and see how Lisp does it, since it has a code formatter built in (here Clozure Common Lisp):

```
? (defun test ()
    (dolist (*print-right-margin* '(80 60 40 30))
      (format t "~%Margin: ~a" *print-right-margin*)
      (pprint '(length (remove-if-not #'(lambda (card) (equal suit (suit card))) hand)))))
TEST
? (test)

Margin: 80
(LENGTH (REMOVE-IF-NOT #'(LAMBDA (CARD) (EQUAL SUIT (SUIT CARD))) HAND))
Margin: 60
(LENGTH (REMOVE-IF-NOT
          #'(LAMBDA (CARD) (EQUAL SUIT (SUIT CARD)))
          HAND))
Margin: 40
(LENGTH
 (REMOVE-IF-NOT
  #'(LAMBDA
     (CARD)
     (EQUAL SUIT (SUIT CARD)))
  HAND))
Margin: 30
(LENGTH
 (REMOVE-IF-NOT
  #'(LAMBDA
     (CARD)
     (EQUAL
      SUIT
      (SUIT CARD)))
  HAND))
```

Even though manually formatted code might look better in many cases, it is useful to get familiar with automatic formatting (aka pretty printing or 'grinding') and being able to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation and the hint with auto-formatting. And thanks, too, for pointing it the indentation-vs-formatting thing :-)

Answer (score 6):

Chris' answer addresses indentation, but there are a few other points, too.  First, **setf** doesn't *declare* global variables.   For that you need **defvar** or **defparameter**, and you should follow the "earmuff" convention:

```
(defparameter *my-hand*
  '((3 hearts)
    (5 clubs)
    (2 diamonds)
    (4 diamonds)
    (ace spades)))
```

You can actually remove some of the indentation issues with **count-suit** by using the keyword arguments to **remove**.  In this case, you want to remove cards with a *different* suit from the hand.  That means you can call **remove** with **suit**, with a negated comparison for the test, and using a key function to get the suit from each card:

```
(defun count-suit (suit hand)
  (length (remove suit hand
                  :key #'suit
                  :test (complement #'eql)))) ; or `:test-not #'eql`
```

```
(count-suit 'diamonds *my-hand*)
;;=> 2
```

But even that's more verbose than it needs to be, since Common Lisp already provides a **count** function that also has a key argument, so that you can do this:

```
(defun count-suit (suit hand)
  (count suit hand :key #'suit))
```

```
(count-suit 'hearts *my-hand*)
;;=> 1
```

Also, with regard to the accessors, you  may be interested in using **defstruct** to define them.  You can tell **defstruct** to use a list as its underlying representation.  This means you can do:

```
(defstruct (card (:type list))
  rank
  suit)
```

```
(make-card :rank 3 :suit 'hearts)
;;=> (3 hearts)
```

```
(card-rank '(ace spaces))
;;=> ace
```

```
(card-suit '(5 clubs))
;;=> clubs
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this:

```
(defun count-suit (suit hand)
  (length (remove-if-not (lambda (card)
                           (equal suit (suit card)))
                         hand)))
```

Alternatively, this is okay too:

```
(defun count-suit (suit hand)
  (length
   (remove-if-not (lambda (card)
                    (equal suit (suit card)))
                  hand)))
```

Note that the `remove-if-not` is only one-space indented from the `length`, since `length` is not a body-containing form. Read [Riastradh's Lisp Style Rules](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt) for more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one question: What do you mean by a "body-containing" form?

Comment: `defun`, `let`, `lambda`, etc. have a section for the code body.

Comment: @GoloRoden But also note that you can define count-suit much more simply in a way that doesn't require so much code: `(count suit hand :key #'suit)`.

Comment: I did not yet know `count`, but of course you are right that this is way cleaner.